# Cannot click web element with JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, click, appium

I'm having a problem finding a working code to simulate a click on a web element (button) on outlook.com mobile website using JS.
I've tried every solution found on the web, but the element is still unclickable.
When tapping this button with my finger (mobile phone) or with the mouse via Chrome devTools it works.

Also, I've found out that when using Selenium/Appium on my mobile phone the click works.

I tried to find the piece of code on selenium's GitHub that performs the click but couldn't find it.
Can someone help me make this click work?

Some details:

website: 
http://outlook.live.com/owa

username:
testclick@outlook.co.il

password:
natasha2018

button - plus button on the left corner
https://ibb.co/h6eVFy

Tested code:

1)
    `elem.click();`

2)

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

3)
 `$("#elem").click();`

4)

```
var simulateClick = function (elem) {
    // Create our event (with options)
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });
    // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your trial code with relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Using plain javascript, you can achieve that using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ms-Button ms-Button--action")[0].click();
```

But, if you are trying to do this via any extensions, then you might need proper permissions before you write this code.

Comment: the class name in my case is "ms-fcl-w o365button" and it does not work :(

Comment: @Dan You may change that accordingly.

Comment: I did, but it does nothing.